# Transforming Xml into valid Html fragments through Xslt using .NET XslCompiledTransform class

Tags: c#, .net, html, xml, xslt

I am trying to use `XslCompiledTransform` in the .NET class library in order to transform an xml string to an Html string. Please consider that I want to use normal strings, not files.

How ca I do this?

It seems that `XslCompiledTransform` only works with files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Load()` also accepts `XmlReader`, and `Transform()` accepts most combinations of `XmlReader` input, and `XmlWriter`, `TextWriter` and `Stream` as output.

So most typically, you might use a `StringWriter` for the output, and a `XmlReader` created from a `StringReader` for the input.

Full example, no files:

```
string xslt = @"<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">
<xsl:output method=""html"" indent=""no""/>
<xsl:template match=""*"">
<p>some html</p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>", xml = @"<xml>boo</xml>";

var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
using (var sr = new StringReader(xslt))
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
{
    transform.Load(xr);
}

using (var sw = new StringWriter())
using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
{
    transform.Transform(xr, null, sw);
    string html = sw.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have use xslt and xml in the form of string ,
which is generated on the same .aspx page,
then converting it to html using StringWriter,
use a literal control to show html,bind  Stringwriter data to it.

string xslt="Add your code for xslt here";//look for any normal xslt file.

string xml="Add your code for xml here";//look for any normal xml file.

```
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(xslt);

        XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr);

        transform.Load(xr);


        StringReader srxml = new StringReader(xml);

        XmlReader xrxml = XmlReader.Create(srxml);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        transform.Transform(xrxml, null, writer);

        Literal1.Text = writer.ToString();

        writer.Close();
```